# Redirecting visitors between store views of different websites

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, multistore

To make a long story short I want to redirect visitors from one store view to another. I assume I can do it with following url `http://sld.tld/?___store=code2&___from_store=code1`. However it is not working. Stores views belong to different websites. All websites have same domain without any trailing codes.

My debugging led me to `Mage_Core_Model_App` where somewhere around lines `534`-`547` the following code can be found:

```
    /**
     * prevent running a store from another website or store group,
     * if website or store group was specified explicitly in Mage::run()
     */
    $curStoreObj = $this->_stores[$this->_currentStore];
    if ($type == 'website' && $storeObj->getWebsiteId() == $curStoreObj->getWebsiteId()) {
        $this->_currentStore = $store;
    }
    elseif ($type == 'group' && $storeObj->getGroupId() == $curStoreObj->getGroupId()) {
        $this->_currentStore = $store;
    }
    elseif ($type == 'store') {
        $this->_currentStore = $store;
    }
```

However I got no adjustments made to my `index.php` and `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']` variable is not set.

So the question is what else can *explicitly* set the store view or what the hell is going on?

Comment: What's going on in `App::_checkGetStore()`?

Comment: All stock. No mods. `$storeObj` is valid and active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All websites have same domain without any trailing codes.

It is a wrong part, you can't have 2 websites with the same domain and url in magento. You should either have separate domains or separate urls.